# Что быстрее работает статический метод или не статический?

Tags: java, static, методы

Что быстрее работает статический метод или не статический, в джаве?
Пытался найти документацию на этот счет но не смог, буду рад если кто-то сможет ответить на этот вопрос

Comment: За счёт чего по Вашему может различаться скорость?

Comment: за счет оптимизаций компилятора, которые он может выполнять над статическими методами и не статическими. За счёт способа хранения статических методов и не статических и может еще что-то

Comment: Вся разница в наличии ссылки на объект(this) в нестатических методах.

Comment: @vp_arth это не вся разница. Нестатические методы в Java всегда виртуальны.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Во-первых:** не делайте выбор между статическим и не статическим методом на основе производительности.

**Второе:** на практике это не будет иметь никакого значения. HotSpot может выбрать оптимизацию способами, которые ускоряют статические вызовы для одного метода, а не статические вызовы быстрее для другого.

**В-третьих:** значительная часть мифов, окружающих статические и нестатические, основаны либо на очень старых JVM (которые нигде не приближаются к оптимизации, которую делает Hotspot), либо какие-то запоминающиеся мелочи о C ++ (в которых динамический вызов использует еще один доступ к памяти чем статический вызов).

[Источник.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3805191/6677992)